# How do I use a bat file to call other bat files which are in different folders as I keep getting errors

Tags: windows, batch-file, method-call

So I am trying to write a bat file that calls 3 different bat files in 3 different locations.
My `CallAll` batch file is saved in the location:

```
"C:\Users\Documents\CallAll\CallAll.bat"
```

This is the code in my `CallAll` bat file:

```
echo %DATE% %TIME%
call C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
call "C:\Users\Documents\Change\Loading.bat"
call "C:\Users\Documents\Convert\Runjob - XML.bat"
call "C:\Users\Documents\Result\RunModel.bat"
echo %DATE% %TIME%
pause
```

When I run the bat file, I get an error with the calling the first bat file which uses some files in that folder area:

```
(base) C:\Users\Documents\CallAll>java -jar standalone.jar -c Map.xml -o CSV XML
Error: Unable to access jarfile standalone.jar
```

Now I can see that it is trying to find this file in the location I run and not the location where it actually is but I do not know how to solve this

I tried using  `%~dp0` instead of the `C:\Users\Documents` but I did not get anywhere and I don't think I am using this correctly and I am struggling to understand how to use it even though I have looked at various posts

Could someone show and explain a method that works please if possible?

I have looked at other posts but they have not helped me nor have I understood what has been done

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are you sure, when you modified your paths to post them here, that you didn't make a typo? `C:\Users\Documents\CallAllBatchFiles` vs `C:\Users\Documents\CallAll`.

Comment: yes thats a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[untried]

```
call :foreign "C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat"
... repeat pattern
pause
goto :eof

:foreign
pushd "%~dp1"
call %1
popd
goto :eof
```

When you `call` a batch, unless you take action otherwise, any file access will be assumed to be with respect to the current directory at the time the `call` was made.

The `:foreign` subroutine should change to the directory of the required batch (ie. make *that* directory current) [**PUSHD**] and then run the batch, then restore the original directory [**POPD**] and return.

Note the `goto :eof` after the `pause` which will terminate the main batch, skipping over the subroutine.

The `goto :eof` after the `popd` terminates the `:foreign` subroutine.

`:eof` is defined by `cmd` as `end of the batch file` and does not have to be declared.

See `pushd /?` and `popd /?` from the prompt for docco.

Comment: Okay this makes so much sense thank you for the thorough explanation